# Inserting Facebook login and Geolocation data into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, facebook, geolocation, database

I'm currently working on a project where a User logs in with Facebook, sees a map with their location pinpointed, and then can see their friends who have also logged in on the map (with the distance).

The next step is to store this data in a database.

As I'm fairly new to using MongoDB, I would like some guidance on how to approach taking the Facebook login/Geolocation data and inserting it into the database. I'm comfortable with inputting BSON objects into the database manually from the command line, but I cannot seem to find the best way of doing this in my code.

The code is below - it would really help to have some guidance on first steps to getting the post data and putting it into the MongoDB database. Thank you!

```
var express = require('express')
var passport = require('passport')
var util = require('util')
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
var logger = require('morgan')
var session = require('express-session')
var sessionStore = require('sessionstore');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var markers = [];
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var passportStrategy = require('../utils/passport-strategy');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');

var FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "*";
var FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = "*";

passport.use(passportStrategy.facebook);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});

var sessionData = session({
  store: sessionStore.createSessionStore(),
  secret: "your_secret",
  cookie: { maxAge: 2628000000 },
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
});

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    process.nextTick(function () {

      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));

var app = express();

  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(sessionData);
  app.use(logger("combined"));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));
  app.use(methodOverride());
  app.use(session({
      secret: "keyboard cat",
      saveUninitialized: true, // (default: true)
      resave: true, // (default: true)
    }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'),
  function(req, res){
  });

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/mapjs', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/map.js');
});


// Socket markers start

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('marker', function(data) {
      data.socketId = socket.id;
      markers[socket.id] = data;
      console.log('marker latitude: ' + data.lat + ', marker longitude:' + data.lng);
      socket.broadcast.emit('show-marker', data);
    });

    // socket.on('show-marker', )
    socket.on('show-user-location', function(data) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('show-user-location', data);
    });

});

app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('five minute catch up is on port 3000');
});

// socket markers end

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login')
}

module.exports = server;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you strip this down so that you are doing only the insertion of some static data before connecting it up to facebook and having sockets in there.  Every extra bit of code will get in the way of knowing whether what change you try is actually doing what you want.

Regarding the best way to insert data programmatically in mongodb, I believe this is the relevant part of the documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-introduction/

```
db.users.insert(
  {
    name: "sue",
    age: 26,
    status: "A"
  }
)
```